# default tag for all jsp pages (with doctype,styles etc...)

Tags: html, jsp

I have more .jsp files and i have page.tag which contains information about all .jsp files - so i don't want to have doctype, styles and scripts in every .jsp, but just in one tag, because if i want to change something i have to change it in all .jsp's. So assume i have index.jsp which shows page.tag:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>

<t:page title="index">
    <div id="content">
       huge content of the index page..
    </div>
</t:page>
```

and my page.tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<%@attribute required="true" name="title" type="java.lang.String" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>${title}</title>
    <styles and other info required for every .jsp>
</head>
<body>
   <!-- HERE I WANT TO SHOW THE <DIV> FROM INDEX.JSP -->
</body>
</html>
```

I'm passing only title as parameter to the tag. Can I somehow pass the content of the current jsp which is in  tag? Therefore I think it's impossible to pass contents of the jsp's as parameter (as title) because the contents can be huge. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with jsp include:

```
<jsp:include page="header.jsp?title=the+title" />
```

But in your header.jsp to do this with EL, you need to be aware that you'll be reading a request parameter rather than request attribute, so it will have to be like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<c:set var="title_param_name" value="title" />
<html>
<head>
    <title>${param[title_param_name]}</title>
    <styles and other info required for every .jsp>
</head>
<body>
```

You have to use the c:set because it doesn't work with something like ${param["title"]} directly.

Then

```
<jsp:include page="footer.jsp" />
```

with the rest in footer.jsp. Or, for this one you could use `<jsp:include page="footer.html" />` if you really will only have html in it:

```
</body>
</html>
```